# Domain Driven Design CQRS and the save button

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

This may be a dumb question, but I don't know how to solve this.

I am moving from CRUD to Domain-Driven Design with CQRS.

I have seen many DDD examples like [this](https://github.com/kgrzybek/modular-monolith-with-ddd). You could find many more on Github.

The domain model has methods like `changeDetails`, `addSomething`, `removeSomething`, etc., and the commands could be just like that.

But in the UI, I have only 1 page with all its information, and everything is updated by clicking a single **Save** button.

---

How could I trigger all of the commands in 1 click?

If all commands are triggered and 1 fails, could the information be inconsistent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get to this problem, I think you need to redesign your UI and create a more task based UI, you do change one thing at the time. Just like for example when you buy something on Amazon.com, then you don't complete your order with just one big save button, instead it takes you on a journey, adding credit card details, selecting shipping, adding address, confirming the order.....

see this video [Finding your service boundaries: a practical guide](https://particular.net/webinars/finding-your-service-boundaries-a-practical-guide)

Comment: But sometimes you would like the CRUD-based UI. For example on Amazon, you don't want to update the title, update the description, but you want to update all of them in one click.

Comment: In DDD, a command/operation should only affect one aggregate at the time, as your aggregate is your transaction boundary and the "Save all" button is an anti-pattern as it will do to much, and as you say, you will have a problematic error handling, as what if one command fails? then you add complexity by adding transaction and eventually, you end up in a very complex and poorly performing system....

Comment: You are absolutely right about the error handling. Moving from CRUD to DDD is difficult because of changing the mindset, but I have to move on for better sake :)

Comment: Yes, I really think its good to have constraints and limitations that the CQRS/DDD enforces up on us, it really makes it difficult to take bad shortcuts that will make it more complex in the long run.